# bower installation failed.. npm is errors?

Tags: bower-install

> install bower i have probleme
>
> i'm use this command : sudo npm install bower -g

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: bower
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/ahmad/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bower" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ahmad
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: bower
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ahmad/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

> my npm varsion is : 1.1.4
>
> and my node version is : v0.6.12

Answer (score 0):

The registry call is an HTTPS request, which looks like it's failing.  You may be experiencing network connectivity issues, or perhaps it's an improperly set proxy, or perhaps your antivirus software is blocking web requests from npm.